# Would this reworking of my rejected migrated question be acceptable for the Main.SE?

Tags: discussion

[Rejected Migrated Question Here](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/what-are-the-specs-of-the-components-i-would-need-to-make-a-1050-kph-non-rocket)

[Reworking here:](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6969/would-this-question-be-allowed-to-migrate-to-physics-main/6970#6970)

Comment: I really need to figure out what to extract from those links to make this make more sense... Maybe...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Short answer*** - no.

---

***Long answer*** - I don't think there's a way to salvage your super bike question so that it would be constructive for the Engineering site.

**Why?**

There's two main parts as to why your question isn't a good fit for the site.  The first is that your question lives within fantasy and not within the real world.

The [current world record holder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorcycle_land-speed_record) for that category came in at ~605 kph.  Technology gains over the last 25 years brought about a measly 85 kph in improvements, and you're looking to best the current record by ~450 kph.

The parts required to "spec out" your bike would rely heavily upon [unobtanium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtainium).  That's a really bad sign regarding the quality of answers your question would likely attract.  Said another way, the parts you need simply don't exist and aren't within the grasp of a reasonable R&D budget.

If it could have already been done or even reasonably closely been done, it would have.  There's a lot of bragging rights for the manufacturers who are involved in breaking those records.

The second major issue with your question is that it's simply too big.  There's a lot of components that have to specified in order to construct a motorcycle.  Specifying the minimum capabilities of what each of those components would have to reasonably support in order to reach 1050 kph would simply require too long of an answer.

As a rule of thumb, if a question needs more than 3 or 4 paragraphs to properly answer, then the question is too broad for the StackExchange format.

---

All that said, I don't think  you have a *bad* question, just a question that doesn't fit the StackExchange Q&A format.  Big, hypothetical, provoke discussion type questions don't work well with StackExchange.  The questions that work are focused on specific problems or challenges that can be given meaningful and specific answers.

Comment: The 3-4 paragraphs heuristic is super rough but I agree this would be too broad for SE. Consider instead looking for a discussion-centric community focused on motorcycles and/or automotive engineering, that's up for a wide-open challenge.